# Looping HTML5 audio with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I am using a very basic HTML5 audio script and I would simply like the song to loop. How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

```
$(".play").click(function(){
    var snd = new Audio("bells.mp3");
    snd.play();
});
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_loop Here's one example.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate, searched SO but didn't see that one.

Comment: @APAD1 no problem, I just happened to remember it existed and wanted to make sure you saw that `loop` hasn't always worked in case you want to support legacy browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `loop` property to `true`

```
$(".play").click(function(){
    var snd = new Audio("bells.mp3");
    snd.loop = true;
    snd.play();
});
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks! Will accept answer in 9 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the loop attribute in your HTML mark-up

```
<audio loop>
   <source src="bells.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
<audio>
```

No JavaScript needed

Comment: Thanks for the response, using Javascript so I can fire the audio when another function is triggered.

Comment: No Javascript needed, but no Javascript control, either. The OP is using a script - this won't help.

Comment: If this would only loop seamlessly :/